# How do I select text between two “bookmarks” in Word VBA?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, bookmarks

I used the code you provided for this previous question but I am getting the Compile Error:  Sub or Function not defined.  I'm using VBA 7.1 and Word 2016.

```
Sub SelectTextBetweenBookmarks()

    Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("START").Range
    Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("END").Range

    Range(rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End).Select

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you received is usually caused by a missing End Sub or End Function statement. However, your posted code was fine in the regard.

The two issues that needed correction was declaring the ranges and setting the range. Here's revised code that works.

```
Sub SelectTextBetweenBookmarks()
Dim rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range
Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("START").Range
Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("END").Range

Selection.SetRange rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End
End Sub
```

BTW - Welcome to the forum and when you get a chance, take a look at forum's [Code of Conduct](https://superuser.com/conduct). It has a lot of good information links in it for getting the most out of the forum.